# Defining a non-blocking verification function, nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have two functions:

```
function manipulateData(data,callback)

function isDataValid(data)
```

The first one is supposed to manipulate the data and return nothing, and the second one is supposed to return true of false depending on the data's structure, without manipulating it at all.

Assuming three things:

-The manipulation doesn't require a valid data.

-The data's validation process is quite demanding IO wise.

-The data's validation process should receive the original data.

How can I use the verification function as the callback argument, so I'd be able to verify it in the background, and only throw an error from the first function, if the data is found invalid?

I want it to behave like this, where the first statement runs in the background and doesn't block the data manipulation.

```
function manipulateData(data, callback){ 
         if(callback(data)==false){ return some error }
         ...manipulate data without waiting for the verification...
}
```

I hope it is indeed doable and that I'm not missing a crucial logical part in the callback mechanism.

Comment: are you familiar with Promises?

Comment: No, I'm fairly new to nodejs.

Comment: Here's a good reference for you: https://github.com/kriskowal/q Using promises will let you achieve what you want here.

Comment: @BrianGlaz: It's worth noting that Promises are built in to Node - you don't need a library to use them, unless you want some of the additional functionality the library would provide.

Comment: "*I'd be able to verify it in the background*" - no, the verification still runs on the main thread. Only the IO part will happen in the background. By putting something in an asynchronous callback, you only defer it to a later time, you do not move if off the main thread.

Comment: You first say that "*`manipulateData` is supposed to manipulate the data and return nothing*", but later you say that it should a) start the asynchronous verification process, b) manipulate the data and c) (synchronously?!) throw an error if the verification failed? And why would you pass `isDataValid` as the `callback` to do that? That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with callbacks or Promises. With callbacks you want to use something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), but I'd definitely go with Promises (or async/await).

You said that validation was I/O heavy so we'll assume that is an async function. I've assumed that the manipulation is not, but it doesn't really matter once you use `Promise.all` to wrap them up.

The following is tested in Node 6.10. It tests validation failure and success and I'm pretty sure I've got it testing with each function finishing before the other, but again `Promise.all` takes care of that for you anyway.

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

function manipulateData (data, zzz) {
  if (zzz) {
    sleep(zzz);
  }
  return 'manipulated data';
}

function isDataValid (data) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (data) {
      resolve('ok');
    } else {
      reject(new Error('nok'));
    }
  });
}

function updateData (data, zzz) {
  return Promise.all([
    isDataValid(data),
    manipulateData(data, zzz)
  ]);
}

function testIt (data, zzz) {
  return updateData(data, zzz)
  .then(([result, data]) => console.log(`Success! ${result} - ${data}`))
  .catch(err => console.log(`Fail! ${err}`));
}

testIt(true, 0)
.then(() => testIt(false, 0))
.then(() => testIt(true, 1000))
.then(() => testIt(false, 1000));
```

---

Success! ok - manipulated data

Fail! Error: nok

Success! ok - manipulated data

Fail! Error: nok

Comment: Nitpick: You cannot "*go with Promises (**or** async/await)*", you only can go with promises **and** async/await.

Comment: 8) fair call Bergi.

Comment: So basically, regarding the actual invocation in the end of the call,
each `testIt` call is invoked when the previous returned, meaning when the promise is fulfilled. if it is rejected, since no rejection function was provided, it inherits the rejection function of the promise it was called upon, which is the last line in `testIt`. Did I understand it properly?

Comment: yeh, so you wouldn't use it chained like that. The `catch` within the testIt function would catch the errors. Your code would want to implement the contents of testIt with `then` and `catch` adapted to your needs.